# set selected to radio button Flutter

Tags: flutter, radio-button

How to set radio button to selected based on String value fetched from API?

I have an async function that does the API call and fetches the user profile. I need to set the selected gender to the radio button.
I tried calling SetState() from an async function but it results in infinite loop call for build().

Below is my code:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  if(isProfileExists) {
    getProfileDetails();
    print("selected radio : "+selectedRadio.toString());
    if(selectedRadio >= 0) {
      setMemberType(selectedRadio);
    }
  }
  double width=MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
  double height=MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

  Future<bool> _onWillPop() async {
    Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, '/home', ModalRoute.withName('/home'));
  }

  return new WillPopScope(
    child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          _userName+"\'s Profile ",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {},
              child: Icon(
                Icons.save
              ),
            )
          ),
        ],
      ),
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: Container(
        height: height,
        width: width,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20.0, 0, 10.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            SingleChildScrollView(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: (){},
                    child:  TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Bio"),
                      controller: bioTextController,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Text("Basic Information", style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black54,
                      fontSize: 14.0
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Height"),
                  controller: heightTextController,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Weight"),
                  controller: weightTextController,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "BMI"),
                  controller: bmiTextController,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Target Weight"),
                  controller: targetWeightTextController,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Date Of Birth"),
                  controller: dateOfBirthController,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Age"),
                  readOnly: true,
                  controller: ageTextController,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                Text("Gender"),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                     Radio(
                       value: 0,
                       groupValue: radioValue,
                       onChanged: setMemberType,
                     ),
                     Text("Female" ),
                     Radio(
                       value: 1,
                       groupValue: radioValue,
                       onChanged: setMemberType,
                     ),
                     Text("Male"),
                   ],
                 ),
  ...
```

And the set state function is below:

```dart
void setMemberType(int i) {
  setState(() {
    radioValue = i;
    if(i == 0)
      _gender = "F";
    else
      _gender = "M";
  });
}
```

Comment: Separate the radio value names maleRadioValue femaleRadioValue, then in your setState use a ternary operator based on the api value.

Answer (score 0):

You cannnot call `setState` from your `build` method.

Remove this:

```
if(isProfileExists) {
  getProfileDetails();
  print("selected radio : "+selectedRadio.toString());
  if(selectedRadio >= 0) {
    setMemberType(selectedRadio);
  }
}
```

Instead, use an `initState` inside the State of your Stateful Widget:

```
@override
void initState() {
  if(isProfileExists) {
    getProfileDetails();
    if(selectedRadio >= 0) {
      radioValue = selectedRadio;
    }
  }
}
```